# Grails oauth is not functioning

Tags: grails, oauth, grails-plugin

I'm very new to Grails, and I'm trying the Oauth plugin.

I configured my plugin as here:

```
oauth {
        providers {
            twitter {
                api = TwitterApi
                key = 'xxxxx'
                secret = 'xxxxx'
            }
        }
        debug = true
}
```

and added the link in my gps file like this:

```
<oauth:connect provider="twitter">Connect to Twitter</oauth:connect>
```

but when I run my app and click on the `Connect to Twitter` link I been taken to :

`http://localhost:8080/oauth/twitter/authenticate`

why this is happening. This looks so wired. Rather than taking me to the twitter page for login its taking me here.

Where I have been making the mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you sign up on Facebook developers you have to write a callback url, I can't remember right now if Twitter asks for it too, but you should check.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter requires a callback URL to be passed. Please pass an additional attribute in your oauth providers as following:

```
oauth {
        providers {
            twitter {
                api = TwitterApi
                key = 'xxxxx'
                secret = 'xxxxx'
                callback = 'http://<your-web-site>/<application-namespace>/<controller>/<action>'
            }
        }
        debug = true
}
```

Please add the website to your hosts file if you're working on a development machine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link for [Integration with twitter using Grails Oauth Plugin](http://www.jellyfishtechnologies.com/grails-2-2-0-integration-with-twitter-using-grails-oauth-plugin/).
Hope it will help you.
Enjoy.